# Relations not updated on Save with GORM (Golang)

Tags: go-gorm

When I try to update a One To Many relation on a existing entry, the relations are not updated. In my case I want a relation to be removed, but It is not. My models:

```js
type CardMCQ struct {
 gorm.Model
 Question  string   `valid:"required"`
 Answers   []Answer `valid:"required"`
 StackID   uint     `valid:"required"`
 CreatorID string   `valid:"required"`
}

// Answer ...
type Answer struct {
 gorm.Model
 Format    string `valid:"required"`
 IsCorrect bool
 CardMCQID uint
}
```

Then I just call : `db.Save(cardMCQ).Error`, but as I said the relations are not updated. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the memory address of the object you're trying to save/update. Try,
`db.Save(&cardMCQ).Error`